# iTunes only ask for iPad & retina screenshots not iPhone screenshot

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6

[image]I am developing a universal iOS app. When am trying to upload my app to iTunes it only ask for iPad & retina screenshots not iPhone screenshot. I need to upload both iPad & iPhone screenshots. kindly advice me for solve this problem, Thanks in advance...

Comment: please provide more details about the project and the issue itself. your current question is too generic to be answered generally only.

Comment: @holex now check my question

Comment: Here 3.5 inch retina(iPhone 4s) and 4 inch retina(iPhone 5,5s). upload there

Comment: @SunnyShah but I developed for iOS 6 and above...

Comment: that does not matter for the screenshot...

Comment: @SunnyShah when i try to upload the iPhone's screenshots it shows "Screenshots for 4-inch iPhone 5 and iPod touch (5th generation) Retina display must be 1136x640, 1136x600, 640x1136 or 640x1096 pixels, at least 72 DPI, in the RGB color space, and in the JPG or PNG format"

Comment: @iBeginner you can not put screenshot at any size. you screenshow should be in same size as they shows.

Comment: @iBeginner, what are the dimensions of your screenshots? could you also share that info with us, please? I'm just still not understanding your question, the list clearly has slot for the 3.5" and 4" iPhone screenshots...

Answer (score 0):

It does ask for iPhone screenshots.

3.5 inch Retina Display Screenshots are for iPhone 4 and 4S.

4 inch Retina Display Screenshots are for iPhone 5, 5S and 5C.

Comment: when i try to upload the screenshots it shows "Screenshots for 4-inch iPhone 5 and iPod touch (5th generation) Retina display must be 1136x640, 1136x600, 640x1136 or 640x1096 pixels, at least 72 DPI, in the RGB color space, and in the JPG or PNG format"

Comment: am not developing the app for retina display screens

Comment: Apple requires you to support retina displays and newer hardware. If you don't support it might be a reason for your app to get rejected from review process. Either way you must upload retina version of your screenshots. Non-retina screenshots are no longer supported.

Comment: You can not submit apps built with XCode 4.5 , You must use XCode 5.1.1. And apps built with XCode 4.5 and iOS 6SDK no longer supported. You will get an error when trying to publish to app store.